# python smbus/i2c frequency

Tags: python, i2c, raspberry-pi

I would like to change i2c bus frequency in order to allow for slightly longer cables.

I am using python-smbus package and it does work very well, however, I am unable to find how to set the bus frequency.

I have looked through the [docs](http://wiki.erazor-zone.de/wiki%3alinux%3apython%3asmbus%3adoc) but was unable to find anything even remotely related to setting bus parameters.

Is that anything that could be done in python or do I need something lower level?

I am using Raspberry PI, which is an ARM architecture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now spent some significant amount of time researching all the options. It turns out that there are indeed low lever registers as specified in the other post, however, the Raspberry-Pi's driver resets their value on its every use, making any modification to them pretty much useless. The solution is to either write a custom i2c driver or simply wait for an updated version.

Some lower-level information could be found in [byval forum](http://www.byvac.com/forum/read.php?4,71).

Answer (score 3):

On the Raspberry Pi with the latest Jessie image, you can use this to check the current I2C frequency:
`sudo cat /sys/module/i2c_bcm2708/parameters/baudrate`.

To change the frequency, you can add/change this parameter:

`dtparam=i2c_baudrate=50000`

(replace 50000 with the desired frequency) in:

`/boot/config.txt`

and reboot to change the frequency.

Comment: With Jessie on a RPi3, there is no `/sys/module/i2c_bcm2708/parameters/baudrate`, only `/sys/module/i2c_bcm2835/parameters/debug`.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to do something at a lower level.  Typically this stuff is setup by the [board file](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/blob/rpi-3.2.27/arch/arm/mach-bcm2708/bcm2708.c) in the kernel.  I didn't see anything specifically being done with the i2c, other than allocating the resources, so it's likely just using the default clock divisor.  If you look on page 28 of the [datasheet](http://www.element14.com/community/docs/DOC-43016/l/broadcom-datasheet-for-bcm2835-soc-used-in-raspberry-pi), you'll see that the default is 0x5dc.  You'll need to setup that register with a different value (probably bigger) to cope with the longer cables.